# How do I make mouseover actions in jQuery continue

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I am trying to build some hover-buttons that move a DIV-box when hovered. I am using mouse over for this, but this only makes the DIV-box move once, whereas I would like it to continue to move as long as the button is hovered.

Is this possible?

This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<title>jQuery tests</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .div1{
        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 7px;
        top:50px;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .but{
        border-style: dashed;
        padding: 2px;
        margin:2px;
        width: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:310; align:center;">
    <div class="but" id="up">Up</div>
    <div class="but" id="left" style="float:left;">Left</div>
    <div class="but" id="right" style="float:left;">Right</div>
    <div class="but" id="down">Down</div>
    <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
<script>

        $('#left').on('mouseover', function(){
                $('.div1').animate({'left':'-=50'},100);
        });
        $('#right').on('mouseover', function(){
                $('.div1').animate({'left':'+=50'},100);
        });
        $('#up').on('mouseover', function(){
                $('.div1').animate({'top':'-=50'},100);
        });
        $('#down').on('mouseover', function(){
                $('.div1').animate({'top':'+=50'},100);
        });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Think you need to look into `setinterval` and use a variable to check of you are on the div with your mouse (`mouseover`,`mouseout`). `mouseover` is only triggered once, so you can't use that for what you want.

Comment: This may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331439/jquery-how-can-i-continue-an-animation-while-the-mouse-hovers-over-an-element

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` to do it!

Here's a jsFiddle doing it on the right hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/vN2da/

Please note that you need to set a `mouseleave` event to clear the Interval.

**## EDIT ##**

I've updated the jsFiddle to do it on the all directions:

http://jsfiddle.net/vN2da/1/

I hope this be usefull for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Function on animation and bind the same function after animate completes.

```
var anim = true;
function animateAll(dir, ln, speed)
{
    if(anim)
    {
        var opt = {};
        opt[dir] = ln;
        $('.div1').animate(opt, speed, function(){
               animateAll(dir,ln, speed)
        });
    }
}

$('#left').mouseover(function() {
    anim=true;
    animateAll('left','-=50px', 100);
});
$('#top').mouseover(function() {
    anim=true;
    animateAll('top','-=50px', 100);
});
$('#right').mouseover(function() {
    anim=true;
    animateAll('left','+=50px', 100);
});
$('#down').mouseover(function() {
    anim=true;
    animateAll('top','+=50px', 100);
});
$('#left, #top, #right, #down').mouseout(function() {
    anim = false;
});
```

My New Solution for all sides..

Take a Look At [this - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GokulJai/xBD4B/9/)