# How can i make this function infinite while hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, infinite

this function changes the classes of my links to change color when i hover on them, but they only change once when i hover. how can i make it so while i'm hovering the class keeps changing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".nav a").hover(function(e){
            var randomClass = getRandomClass();
            $(e.target).attr("class", randomClass);
        });
        $(".text a").hover(function(e){
            var randomClass = getRandomClass();
            $(e.target).attr("class", randomClass);
        });
    function getRandomClass(){
        var classes = new Array("green", "purple", "teal", "violet", "pink", "red", "yellow", "blue", "magenta", "orange");
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
        return classes[randomNumber];
    }
    </script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `setInterval`.

Like this:

```
var textInterval;

$(".text a").hover(function(e) {
  var evt = e;
  textInterval = setInterval(function() {

    var randomClass = getRandomClass();
    $(evt.target).attr("class", randomClass);

  }, 200); //change 200 for the timing you want the interval to repeat in ms 
}, function(e) {
  //clear interval when uses moves mouse away
  clearInterval(textInterval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep changing the class while you're moving mouse hover the link, you can just change the event "hover" to the "mousemove":

https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

If you want to change class while you're hovering the link but not moving the mouse, you can set a interval to keep changing:

[jQuery - How can I continue an animation while the mouse hovers over an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331439/jquery-how-can-i-continue-an-animation-while-the-mouse-hovers-over-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

Check below jsFiddle link

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pankaj_Ladhar/kge3fsps/5/)

```
$(".text a").hover(function(e) {
    var evt = e;
    textInterval = setInterval(function() {

        var randomClass = getRandomClass();
        $(evt.target).attr("class", randomClass);

    }, 10); //change 200 for the timing you want the interval to repeat in ms 
}, function(e) {
    //clear interval when uses moves mouse away
    clearInterval(textInterval);
    var randomClass = getRandomClass();
    $(e.target).attr("class", randomClass);
});

function getRandomClass() {
    var classes = new Array("green", "purple", "teal", "violet", "pink", "red", "yellow", "blue", "magenta", "orange");
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    return classes[randomNumber];
}
```